# loop a sequence of s3 parquet file path with same schema and save in a single dataframe in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

What is needed to a seq of s3 location is given. The difference for any two location is the partition column value of the table.

Each parquet folder has same schema .

So we need to loop the sequence of s3 parquet file path with same schema and save in a single dataframe in scala along.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array with all of directories you want to import you can iterate over that array and make a collection of dataframes and then union them into a single one.

Try something like this.

```
//You have now a collection of dataframes
val dataframes = directories.map(dir =>
      spark.read.parquet(dir))

//Let's union them into one
val df_union = dataframes.reduce(_ union _)
```

Comment: did it solved your problem @ABHISHEK KUMAR?

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the options, then simply you can load the files recursively.

```
spark.read.parquet("s3a://path/to/root/")
```

The options are as follows.

```
spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories    true
spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive    true
```

This can be used in a way that

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("local[2]")
    .setAppName("test")
    .set("spark.hive.mapred.supports.subdirectories","true")
    .set("spark.hadoop.mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive","true")

val spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf).getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.parquet("s3a://path/to/root/")
```